# Is GPU is not at all used for Tegra 2 devices?

Tags: android, gpu, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-x, tegra

I am porting a game from ios to android using cocos2dx. For tegra 2 device , GPU - Ulp Geforce i am getting 20-22 fps.

In my game we have lots of sprites and also have an hud layer along with level map. 
i got 50-52 fps after removing the map from the level.

Is it possible that GPU is not at all used for Tegra 2 devices leading to 20fps?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I have parallax background with only 5 sprites. On Acer A500 with tegra 2 there is 20 - 25 fps.

On ipad it is 59-60, on xperia mini pro and desire hd devices it is 60-62.

We have two versions of reason:

1. cocos2d-x
2. tegra 2

Today we'll try to make the same background without cocos2d-x to try it on tegra. I'll report about results.

Comment: The result of our experiment: 25-30 fps on tegra 2, 62 fps on other devices.

Comment: Thanks for your research. so the conclusion is due to tegra 2. Any document or info how to resolve this??